# How to Make a Coffee Plate?

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials, objects, edit-mode

I was watching Blender Guru's tutorial for making donut and coffee with plate, but when it comes to curving the coffee plate, I grab part of it (with *Proportional Editing* switched to sphere) the whole plate comes along and nothing curves.

I followed all steps including adding loop cuts and pressing I to do the thing which he showed.

Comment: you tried wheel up on mouse?

Comment: Wheel up and down will define the influence area (you can also use PAGE UP - PAGE DOWN). Here's the manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html#influence

Comment: Thanks, it helped.